# Couldn't change an old splash image with new image on android app

Tags: android, image

I tried to change the splash image in my android app with a new image, by changing the image in the drawable folder and I giving the same name to new image.

In my Eclipse environment I can see new image on the splash.xml file but when I run the code I see the old image on the emulator. What is wrong?

Comment: if there is no image present in all the drawable folders of your project then uninstall the application from emulator and run the code once again. Because sometimes emulator will not update/refresh properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that splash image is also present in any other folder like drawable-large,drawable-small .

So Please check all the folders.

Please Clean your project once and check again.

Comment: chriag thanxx a lot. I clean the project and it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If the application has [multiple resolutions](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) of the splash image, you need to change them all.

```
/res
  /drawable
  /drawble-xhdpi
  /drawble-hdpi
  etc...
```

Comment: I have changed all folders but ı forgot clean the project thanxxxx